# Difference between LAN and VLAN

Tags: lan, vlan

What is difference between LAN and VLAN. Which one is suited for broadcasting messages How to set up VLAN. What are their advantages and disadvantages

Edit:

If I write a program for VLAN then will it run if I don't have a switch. (Each computer connected to one another just using a cable to form a simple LAN)

Comment: please don't provide answer from Wikipedia. I have already read about VLAN from there.

Comment: should this receive a homework tag?

Comment: @Tyler No - meta tags are discouraged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lan means "Local Area Network" and Vlan stands for "Virtual LAN".
There are no real differences between one and the other except that a vlan is used to create multiple broadcast domains in a switch.
Say for example you have one 48 port layer 2 switch.

If you create 2 vlans, one on ports 1 to 24 and one for ports 25 to 48, you can make one switch act like two.

One advantage of using vlans is that if you segment your network by department like this:
One class C network for Sales
One class C network for IT
etc.

You don't have to use different switches for different networks because you can just use one big switch and create different Vlans for each segment.

How to create a vlan depends on the switch in question.
In a cisco switch you can create vlans like this.

```
SwitchA(config)#configure terminal   (enter in global configuration mode) 
SwitchA(config)#vlan 3               (defining the vlan 3) 
SwitchA(config)#vlan 3 name management (assigning the name management to vlan 3)
SwitchA(config)#exit        (exit from vlan 3)
```

Now assigning the ports 2 and 3 to VLAN 3

```
SwitchA(config)#interface fastethernet 0/2    (select the Ethernet 0 of port 2) 
SwitchA(config-if)#switchport access vlan 3   (allot the membership of vlan 3)
SwitchA(config-if)#exit                       (exit from interface 2)
```

Comment: How many VLAN can I create using a Switch

Comment: If I write a program for VLAN then will it run if I don't have a switch. (Each computer connected to one another just using a cable to form a simple LAN)